# Rails test keeps crashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Everytime I run `rails test` I get this error followed by thousand lines of text:

`Running via Spring preloader in process 51653
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:27: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000110
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]`

Sometimes when I run `bin/spring stop` it fixes the problem temporarily, but then it randomly comes back again.

Any help please?

Comment: if you are using [Spring](https://github.com/oscardelben/firebase-ruby/issues/27)...

Comment: Also, check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569890/rails-s-return-bug-segmentation-fault